How to select the best available cameradevice for all iphones and handle zoom levels like Apple's Camera app in Swift?
I'm developing a custom camera application in Swift and I want to mimic the functionality of Apple's native Camera app and apply best practices. Specifically, I'm trying to:

Use the Best Available Camera: Select the highest quality rear camera available on any iPhone
model (e.g., Ultra Wide, Wide Angle, Telephoto).

Handle Zoom Levels Like Apple Does: Implement zoom functionality where:
A zoom value of 0.5x uses the Ultra Wide camera.
A zoom value of 1x uses the Wide Angle camera.
Higher zoom levels (e.g., 2x, 3x) use the Telephoto camera if available.

Have a working Tap to focus feature.


What should I have in the Device DiscoverySession to use the best possible camera for all current iphone models?
AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [ // Devices here ], mediaType: .video, position: .unspecified).devices
Should I use builtInTripleCamera and builtinDualCamera or should I switch between the camera devices manually depending on zoom factor?
What's the best approach to switch between different cameras based on zoom level? (ignore if I should be using builtInTripleCamera)
Currently when trying to use the tap to focus with builtInTripleCamera it does not seem to work, it only autoExposes, however, in apples camera app it does work?
Current tap to focus implementation:
func setFocusOnTap(devicePoint: CGPoint) {
        guard let cameraDevice = self.deviceInput?.device else { return }
        do {
            try cameraDevice.lockForConfiguration()
            
            // Check if auto-focus is supported and set the focus mode accordingly.
            if cameraDevice.isFocusModeSupported(.autoFocus) {
                cameraDevice.focusPointOfInterest = devicePoint
                cameraDevice.focusMode = .autoFocus
            }
            
            // Set the exposure point and mode for auto-exposure.
            cameraDevice.exposurePointOfInterest = devicePoint
            cameraDevice.exposureMode = .autoExpose
            
            // Enable monitoring for changes in the subject area.
            cameraDevice.isSubjectAreaChangeMonitoringEnabled = true
            
            cameraDevice.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to configure focus: \(error)")
        }
    }

I tried using the builtInTriple camera, but have difficulties with the tap to focus to work.
But mostly im just looking for best practices and the generally best way to implement this
